# Substitution reaction rate for tertiary halide substrate with adjacent carbonyl

Tags: organic-chemistry, nucleophilic-substitution

[image]

In the book "Organic Chemistry" by Clayden et al. p 343 it is stated that this substrate reacts very slowly through both the S<sub>N</sub>1 and S<sub>N</sub>2 pathways. It is shown side by side with neopentyl chloride as an example of notoriously unreactive compounds.

I get that being tertiary might slow down S<sub>N</sub>2 to counteract the effect of the adjacent carbonyl. But why would S<sub>N</sub>1 not still be good?

My question is: why does this substrate react slowly through both S<sub>N</sub>1 and S<sub>N</sub>2?

Comment: You should consider what the transition state of the SN1 reaction looks like.